# ios 5 up ios 6 initial screen with black band

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

Before ios 6 I don't have this problem.
My project was compile for iOs 5.

But in a device with iOs5, i don't know why they have black band was appear on the top like in the picture.
But only on the initial screen. If I go and return to this page it's ok.
No probleme with a device on iOs6.

[image: Black band problem]

Maybe I have forgot something new?

Comment: are you testing it on IOS 6 simulator with 4 inch display?If yes yoo need to provide a new splash screen for your project which has 640x1136 resolution.

Comment: No I have test on reel Ipad 3 (ios5). And in the simulator not 4 inch display